# Password-protect feed and make it usable in major aggregators

Tags: security, rss, feed, password

A WordPress site I'm on uses WordPress's default cookie-based authentication. This means that the RSS feed of the page is password-protected and can only be read when the cookie is available. Unfortunately, this makes it impossible to include the feed into a feed reader like [Feedly](https://feedly.com/), [Inoreader](https://www.inoreader.com), or [Slack](https://paperhive.slack.com/services/7766017874).

Is there a way to export a page's feed in such a way that it is password-protected *and* can be used in major feed aggregators?

Comment: Then what would be the point in password protecting it? People will still be able to access it then.

Comment: People with the password, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a PHP file, which listens for a password through a GET method. Then if the password is correct, include the feed and display the feed?

Then you could only access the page if you use the url `/example/feed.php?password=PASSWORD`

```
<?php
if ($_GET['password'] == 'PASSWORD') {
    include 'path/to/feed';
}
```